# mariadb some records not updated

Tags: sql, mariadb

Is it possible that in the binary logs there is a transaction that occurred but in the storage engine (innodb) it did not update.

for example in the binary log, the transaction is like this. but the id with 2 and 3 are not updated in the storage engine(innodb).

```
   BEGIN
   UPDATE my_table SET status = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 1
   UPDATE my_table SET status = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 2
   UPDATE my_table SET status = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 3
   UPDATE my_table SET status = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 4
   UPDATE my_table SET status = 1, updated_at = NOW() WHERE id = 5
   COMMIT
```

Comment: Which MariaDB version? Could something have set status to not 1 for `id in (2, 3)` after the transaction commited?

Comment: Such issues can be avoided writing simpler update commands like UPDATE my_table SET status = 1 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 5. Or ...WHERE id IN (1,2...) if further id's are affected that don't match a BETWEEN range.

Comment: @danblack
Server version: 10.0.38-MariaDB MariaDB Server
it has a column for timestamp.this is also not updated.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I am wondering what are the possible reasons why there is a transaction in the binary log but not updated in the storage engine.

Comment: That is odd. No it shouldn't happen. If it happens on a [maintained MariaDB version](https://mariadb.org/about/#maintenance-policy) please do a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer, but too long for a comment:

It's more or less impossible to give you an detailled answer without analyzing server logs and binary log file.

**Some comments/hints:**

1. Make sure that the statements belong to the same database, often there are different databases (e.g. backups) with same tables. Run `mysqlbinlog` with option `--database yourdb` to make sure that the statements belong to the same database (Unfortunately mysqlbinlog doesn't show the database name for the [`QUERY_EVENT`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/query_event/), even if this information is part of the event.
2. Compare the timestamp of the Query event with the content of your timestamp columns.
3. *Binary logging is done immediately after a statement or transaction completes but before any locks are released or any commit is done*.
   This means that there is a small window of time in which an error can result in an uncommitted transaction being present in the binary log but not in the database. To avoid this you can use XA transactions.
4. As already mentioned by Dan Black, upgrade MariaDB Server to a more recent version. MariaDB 10.0 was released more than 9 years ago, it reached end of lifetime in 2019. Even if it supports the recent replication protocol (version 4), there were tons of changes, bug fixes and improvements over the last 10 years.